# Should the factory employee one employee and pay extra shift or one employee and a helper?

Tags: calculus

I have a problem in math, but I cannot wrap my head around, can you please help me to break down this problem and help me understand solving it? The problem is as below:

> A company produces units everyday according to the market requests that are made monthly. Most of the work can be covered by one skilled employee.
>   - Hiring one skilled employee costs $\$5000$/month.
>   - If the skilled employee needs to work with extra shift, he has to be paid another extra $\$3000$/month.
>   - On average, $85\%$ of the work is covered by one skilled employee.
>   - To hire a helper costs $\$2500$/month.

1) Should the company hire one employee and pay the extra shifts when needed, or hire one employee and the helper.

2) How much work (on %) should be covered without hiring the helper, so it would be even for both approaches.

Comment: When you say $85\%$ of the work is covered by one skilled employee, do you mean that on a given day, there is an $85\%$ chance that the skilled worker will complete all of the work and a $15\%$ chance that they will not?

Comment: not seeing calculus ... markup and margin yes, calculus no.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee sorry, I did not reallly know on what to tag my question, but you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$85\%$ of the time, the company pays the skilled worker $\$5000$ per month.  The other $15\%$ of the time they pay him $\$8000$.  On average, they pay him $$.85\cdot5000+.15\cdot8000=5450$$

If they hired a helper, the company would pay $\$7500$ per month, so it clearly saves money by paying overtime.

Can you do the second part of the problem now?

**EDIT:**

Say the fraction of time he works overtime is $p$.  If the cost of hiring a helper is the same as paying overtime, we have $$
\begin{align}5000(1-p)+8000p&=7500\\
5000+3000p&=7500\\
p&=\frac56\end{align}
$$
Expressed as a percentage, $p=83.3333\%$

Comment: Second part: so from 7500 dollar of the salary from both employees, if the first employee works 100%, there is still 2050 dollar worth of work until it would be even in salaries for, and if i convert than in terms of %, the first worker has to work 168.3% so the salaries would be even. Can you check please if I am correct?

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori No, this is not correct.  How could he work more than $100\%$ of the time?  I don't understand where $2050$ comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the problem. Here is an alternate interpretation from what saulspatz offered.

If the employee has to work any overtime during the month, they automatically qualify for a $\$3000$ bonus for the month. Otherwise, they only earn $\$5000$ for the month. Assuming 20 work days is standard for the month (they get weekends off), the chances they will complete all of their work every day is $(.85)^{20}$. The chance they will need overtime at least once during the month is $1-(.85)^{20}$. So, their average pay for the month would be:

$$(.85)^{20}\times \$5000 + (1-(.85)^{20})\times \$8000 \approx \$7883.72 > \$7500$$

So, it is more cost effective to hire the helper.

If this interpretation is correct, then the skilled employee would need to complete all work $91.43\%$ of the time in order for the expected salary to balance out with hiring a helper.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we have two situations:

We have the easy one, where the company hires a skilled employee for \$5000/month and a helper for \$2500/month, for a flat expense of \$7500/month total.

The alternative is paying \$5000/month for the one employee, plus an additional \$3000/month 15% of the time, which averages out to \$450/month on top of the usual expenses, for a total of \$5450/month.

This suggests the company should just hire the one employee.

On the second part of the problem, the two will be even when (the employee's bonus * the proportion of the time it's needed) is equal to the cost of hiring a helper. ($b*p=h$). We can rearrange that to $p=h/b$, which in this case gives us $p=2500/3000$, so the two will have an even cost when the employee needs an extra shift 83.33% of the time (in other words, meeting their quota a scant 16.67% of the time).

Comment: If the skilled employee can only complete $16.67\%$ of the all the work, and the "helper" can complete the rest, why bother with the skilled employee at all? Might as well just hire the helper full time, as they can complete $83.33\%$ of the work. This answer does not really make sense. Nor does the problem, unfortunately. I'm not saying you are incorrect, just that the problem is janky.

Comment: It's not that they can only do 16.67% of their work; it's that they can only do all of their work in a single shift 16.67% of the time. That number applies regardless of how much extra time they would need; it's overtime regardless of whether they go over by two minutes or two hours. Having a helper stay for the entirety of the shift cuts down the time it takes to get that work done (presumably such that the duo could make quota 100% of the time).